# Testing CRUD class.

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, crud

I have some issue. Im writing some unit test in my project but i don't know how to test my CRUD methods.. Maybe they are not testable ;/

This is one of my methods:

```
    public static void IncrementInvalidLoginColumn(string login)
    {
        User user;

        using (DTContext context = new DTContext())
        {
            try
            {
                user = context.Users.Where(u => u.Login.CompareTo(login) == 0).FirstOrDefault();

                if (user.InvalidLogins < 3)
                {
                    user.InvalidLogins = user.InvalidLogins + 1;
                }

                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch
            {

            }        
        }            
    }
```

Maybe someone will have idea what should i do.

Comment: you should use dependency injection instead of creating `DTContext`.

Comment: Why the empty catch in `try { ... } catch { }` ?

Comment: This is not important i think ;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so i read all of your posts and they was very helpful. 
I use MOQ framework and this is example how i do it.

This is how Liviu M. told me to do for example:

```
 public class CRUDclass
 {
    private DTContext _context;

    public CRUDclass(DTContext myObj)
    {
        _context = myObj;
    }
 }
```

We have CRUD Class which are doing operations directly on our database. We have constructor with one argument and private field. This our context :)

This is (for example) my method in CRUDclass:

```
public bool AddUser(User user)
{
  try
   {
     _context.Users.Add(user);
     _context.SaveChanges();

     return true;
   }
   catch
   {
     return false;
    }  
 }
```

Ovecourse he have our DTContext class witch DBSet becouse i using entity framework. And after that i am able to write some test method:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void Should_Add_User()
    {
        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<User>>();
        var mockContext = new Mock<DTContext>();

        mockContext.Setup(m => m.Users).Returns(mockSet.Object);

        var usrCRUD = new UserCRUD(mockContext.Object);

        var usr = new User();
        usr.Login = "Login_Name";
        usr.Email = "loginName@test.com";
        usr.Password = "***";
        usr.InvalidLogins = 0;
        usr.RememberID = 0;

        usrCRUD.AddUser(usr);         

        mockSet.Verify(m => m.Add(It.Is<User>(arg => arg.Login == "Login_Name")));            
        mockContext.Verify(m => m.SaveChanges(), Times.Once());
    }
```

At first a have to set my fake object (Mock>).
This test method checks if our user was added to Mock :)

I hope it can help somebody, if anything will be unclear please write a question :)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you mean by "unit" test. If you don't want your test to hit the database then your method is not testable (or at least not without some refactoring).

If hitting the database is acceptable (which would actually be an **integration** test) then you can definitely test your method.

Here are some steps:
1. Arrange the initial data. You use an instance of the `DTContext` directly in the test to put the system in a predefined state (basically you write some user records in the database)

1. You run the method you want to test (which in fact uses its own instance of the `DTContext`)
2. You use `DTContext` again to read the user information directly from the database and assert that the `InvalidLogins` property has incremented.
3. You need to make sure you delete any data that you put in manually.

---

This is the gist of DI:

```
public class Example { 
  private IDatabaseGateway myDatabase; 

  public Example(IDatabaseGateway myDb) { 
    myDatabase = myDb;
  } 

  public void DoStuff() { 
    ... 
    myDatabase.GetData(); 
    ... 
  } 
}
```

You give your business class an abstraction of the database via the constructor, that is you **inject** your dependencies in the class that needs them.

Once you have this in place, in production code you pass in the constructor a concrete instance of IDatabaseGateway that goes to the actual database.

In the case of a unit test you pass it a **mock** instance of the same interface. The mock is a special object that you can setup/configure to return what you want. Various libraries exist for mocking (an easy one is [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4)).

*However without modifying your code too much, it is better to stick with integration testing that hits the database. It will give you a simple and valid test.
Especially since there are some pitfalls in mocking the DbContext in EF (ex. some queries may not work when you will use them in production, testing updates in EF with mocks is a bit trickier).*

Comment: I want to do tests whithout hitting my database. But i first time hear about Dependency Injection. I can't find some simple examples for this in MVVM

Comment: Here is a link that can help you with DI: http://www.jamesshore.com/Blog/Dependency-Injection-Demystified.html

Comment: I just added an answer whilst you were editing that basically says what your edit says ;)

Comment: Sorry for asking but it is new for me, IDatabaseGateway is interface that i have to implement on my own? I have entity framework database model in class User so now i have to implement interface for it ?\

Comment: `IDatabaseGateway` is a custom interface that you create and implement. The interface can have a method called `GetUserById()` that you will set up in the mock configuration. Also it is worth looking at the Repository Pattern: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html

Answer (score 1):

The idea of unit tests is to test your ifs, switches, etc., not the database operations.
In your case you need an interface that is an abstration of DTContext. In the simplest case it might look as the following.

```
public interface IObjectContext : IDisposable
{
    IEnumerable<User> Users { get; }
}
```

In more complicated cases you may need to use `IQueryable<T>` or `IObjectSet<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>`.

Add a partial class declaration of `DTContext` and make it implement `IObjectContext`. Add a constructor to the class that contains the method `IncrementInvalidLoginColumn` with a parameter of type `IObjectContext`. Now you can inject any instance of `IObjectContext` instead of creating it in your class. This instance can be a `DTContext` or a mock for testing. Your class is ready to be tested without connection to a real database.

NB. In case of instances of `IDisposable` it's better to inject a `Func<IObjectContext>` instead of `IObjectContext`. Then you can create an instance for each operation and dispose it immediately after.

Answer (score 1):

If there are CRUD operations in your code then I will recommend to use [MOQ](https://github.com/Moq/moq4) framework for unit testing. Below links are quite helpful:

[Quick Start](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

[Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/182847/An-Introduction-to-MOQ)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would inject your `DTContext` rather than creating a new one every time that the method is called. That way you could mock that object in your unit test and verify that it is called as expected.

Your constructor would look something like:

```
private readonly IDTContext _context;
public CrudClass(IDTContext context)
{
    _context = context
}
```

With your method now looking like

```
public static void IncrementInvalidLoginColumn(string login)
{
    User user;

    try
    {
        user = _context.Users.Where(u => u.Login.CompareTo(login) == 0).FirstOrDefault();

        if (user.InvalidLogins < 3)
        {
            user.InvalidLogins = user.InvalidLogins + 1;
        }

        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch
    {
    // Handle errors
    }        
}
```

And then in your test, if you were using a framework like [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4), you would basically script how that object would behave and test against that. For instance, setting up the mocked `IDTContext` to always return the same user for your `Users` collection and `SaveChanges()` method will write the number of invalid logins to a variable that you could then test against.